# NG Build and NPM start giving errors in ProseMirror under NGx- Editor

Tags: angular

There is a sudden flurry of errors when i am building the code , the errors are inside the Ngx-Editor libraries in Node Modules folder .

Screenshot of errors -

[image]

My Package.Json -

[image]

Can anyone let me know any workarounds ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to how the package declares export, try one of these

`import test from 'test'`

or

`import * as test from 'test'`

Another way is to import `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `tsconfig.json's compilerOptions`

Answer (score 0):

It's a global issue, refer to this
https://github.com/sibiraj-s/ngx-editor/issues/406